# Sqltabledependency can't reach the machine to fire event

Tags: sql, triggers, network-protocols, communication-protocol

recently create a program for detect when ona table in database is changed using sqltabledendency, but when i want to put the consume code in QA ambient, whit another segment of red, this consume program never be fired, because the sqltabledependency never reached.. I think is because the type of protocol is used, if someone know what protocol and ports use the sqltabledependency.. thanks